# array data using php issue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

here is my code the part of the option in php is not working somehow and it will only print team and question only when i tested

```
<?php
 Include("conifdata.php");

$command= "INSERT INTO SoccerPoll (Team, Question, Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $dbh ->prepare($command);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['team'], $_POST['question'],$_POST['option[0]'], $_POST['option[1]'], $_POST['option[2]'], $_POST['option[3]']));
if($stmt ->rowCount()>0){
    echo "Successfull";
}
```

// when tested here it will only print team and question only i need all of them

```
 echo $_POST["team"], $_POST['question'], $_POST['option[0]'], $_POST['option[1]'], $_POST['option[2]'], $_POST['option[3]'];



 //and here is my html page

<h1>Create a Team Poll</h1>
<p>enter data.</p>
<form action="addPoll.php" method="POST">
Team: <input type="text" required name="team"><br>
Question: <input type="text" required name="question"><br>
Option 1: <input type="text" required name="option1"><br>
Option 2: <input type="text" required name="option2"><br>
Option 3: <input type="text" required name="option[]"><br>
Option 4: <input type="text" required name="option[]"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Create Poll">
</form>
```

Comment: replace the commas with periods.

Comment: "option[]" are all this but still cant fix and also i tried both single quote and double quote

Comment: @adeneo Why? `echo` can take multiple arguments and it echoes them all.

Comment: @Barmar - of course it does, confused with JS, and I should have seen those strange keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a parameter name ends with `[...]`, that isn't part of the `$_POST` key, it causes that `$_POST` variable to be a sub-array. You need to access it with multi-dimensional array syntax. So `$_POST['option[0]']` should be `$_POST['option'][0]`, and similarly for all the other elements of that array.

Comment: Thank you this is what i was missing

Answer (score 0):

your `echo` statement has commas, try using the period to concatenate them, or replace the `,` with `." ".` if you want spaces between them

Comment: `echo $foo, $bar` is the same as `echo $foo . $bar`.

Comment: what is wrong with this code ` $command= "INSERT INTO SoccerPoll (Team, Question, Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $dbh ->prepare($command);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['team'], $_POST['question'], $_POST['option[0]'], $_POST['option[1]'], $_POST['option[2]'], $_POST['option[3]']));`